# How to implement Accordion for mobile support of Flexsections course plugin in Moodle 4.0?

Tags: moodle, moodle-mobile

I need to implement the mobile app support for the [Flexsections course format](https://moodle.org/plugins/format_flexsections) in Moodle 4.0. By default the subsections are shown as just another section in the Moodle app like any Topics format. I need to implement the accordion in Ionic 5 using mustasche template and javascript where subsections are collapsed within main sections in the mobile app.

Since this is Ionic 5 I dont have the [ion-accordion component](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/accordion). So I searched the internet on how an accordion is implemented in HTML/CSS/JS as well as Ionic 5 and found this tutorials:

[1.Ionic 5 accordion List](https://sbsharma.com/ionic-accordion-list/)

But since we can only write plain js in the mobile support files of Moodle plugin, I don't know how to implement Accordion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of pages in the app that use an accordion, for example the [message groups](https://github.com/moodlehq/moodleapp/blob/main/src/addons/messages/pages/group-conversations/group-conversations.html#L76). You can see how that's done for inspiration on how to do it in your plugin (take special attention to the `aria-*` attributes such as `aria-expanded` to make them accessible).

I say "for inspiration" because as you mentioned, you can't write new components in plugins. But you should be able to use things such as `CONTENT_OTHERDATA` in your template, and toggle it in the JavaScript. You can learn more about that in the documentation: [Using `otherdata`](https://moodledev.io/general/app/development/plugins-development-guide#using-otherdata)